# One form insert into many tables

Tags: php, mysql

Im using the code bellow to insert data into a table . The table is called year1 .

My question is if I have another table called year2 , how could I use the same form to add data to it , while still using it to add to year1. I was think something along these lines :

There is an extra field that the user can enter the number of the year e.g '1'. this could be compared to the names of the tables and inseretd into the correct one.

To be clear . I want the form to submit into one table (the correct one) and not both at the same time.

```
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$english = $_POST['english'];
$math = $_POST['math'];
$science = $_POST['science'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO year1 ".
       "(firstname,lastname, english, math, science) ".
       "VALUES('$fname','$lname',$english,$math,$science)";
mysql_select_db('education');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
//echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>



<?php } ?>

          <p>Create a new student</p>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">


Firstname: <input name="fname" type="text" id="fname"><br>
Lastname: <input name="lname" type="text" id="lname"><br>
English mark: 
<input name="english" type="number" id="english"><br>
Math's mark: 
<input name="math" type="number" id="math"><br>
Science mark: 
<input name="science" type="number" id="science"><br>

<input name="create" type="submit" id="create" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Just do a second query with the same or different variables.

Comment: I dont want the same data in each table . Think of the tables as classrooms with different people in them

Comment: You could make use of `mysqli_*` then, and use [`multi_query()`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: i dont understand how that would solve the problem

Comment: Why not using the same table with an extra column as the year?

Comment: @Tarik that would make the table way to large when it is displayed .

Comment: @fred is right, do a second query and change the year from 1 to 2 and if you wont it to large just use select on your query.

Comment: @dhidy I understand the second query . How do I make it so that the form only submits into the correct table

Comment: Then use conditional statements to echo what you need to be shown, if you say that your table risks in being too large to display. @user3396245 - I'd love to stick around and help further, but I'm not staying inside on a day like today. The "sun" has precedence today ;-)

Comment: add a `year` field in your form and use conditional if, if `$_POST = 'year1'` do the first query if not do the second one.

Answer (score -1):

Not very clear on what your end goal is. If you want one submit to insert into both tables on each submit, or if you want it to go into the correct table each time, but only one table at a time.

If you want to insert into both tables each time then just create another sql_query with the data.

If you want it to go into just one table but the correct table each time then add another input for the year in the html form then add an if statement in the mysql:

```
// using a ternary. if year is selected use it, if not use year 1
$table = ($_POST['year']) ? $_POST['year'] : 'year1';
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ".
       "(firstname,lastname, english, math, science) ".
       "VALUES('$fname','$lname',$english,$math,$science)";
```

Or you can just put another field in this table for the year and have all the info in one table but the table could get quite large.

Comment: Care to check if the table exists first? Or maybe escape the $_POST variable? No, thought not.

Comment: I try to keep the examples as easy to read for these questions. He should do a-lot more security checks than just table exist and escape $_POST. If I added all of those it would be difficult to see the fix.